# Make "you are commenting on" text more visible

Tags: feature-request, comments, ios-app

When you are commenting on post in the iOS-app you can see red text below that post. If post already contains several answers it is hard to find post where you commenting on without reading the text:

> [image: commenting on]

My request is to highlight text on active post with different color to quickly distinguish post where you commenting on.